# No permission to drop SQLite3 development database Rails 5.0 on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sqlite

I am trying to reset my development Database for my Rails 5.0 project on Windows, but when I run (same as rake db:drop)

```
rails db:drop
```

I get the following error:

> Errno::EACCES Permission denied @ unlink_internal

I restarted my PC already to make sure that rails was not running in anyway

Comment: Are you using a windows admin account?

Comment: I tried to run it as an admin, but that didn't solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: Delete development.sqlite3 by hand, then run rake db:setup db:migrate and you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to exit the Rails Server.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to reset my sqlite3 db on Windows, using rails 5.1.6 while doing the *Learn Enough to Be Dangerous* Rails tutorial. I found the following answer on another post, and it worked for me:

> "For Dropping entire database just give rake db:setup it drops and again creates the database for you."

When I run the command, I get:

```
$ rails db:setup
Database 'db/development.sqlite3' already exists
Database 'db/test.sqlite3' already exists
-- create_table("users", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0497s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0624s
```

And my database seems to work as expected, but with no data.

Answer (score 0):

**This can help**

When I need to remove data base then I use `rake db:reset`.
Please try it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. If I am not mistaken this with under the hood still execute the same rails db:drop, nevertheless I tried it but unfortunately still have the same issue

Comment: My suggestion is that install a linux machine for ruby development. Because there are several problems while working in Windows.

Comment: db:reset is just a wrapper for db:drop + db:create. This is very unlikely to help.

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution:

In windows machine you would have to specify that it is an unsafe move, so i

```
rake db:drop_unsafe
rails db:migrate
```

this is for windows machine, if you're using Linux then you can do just

```
rake db:reset
```

Comment: It should be `rake db:drop:_unsafe` (notice the missing colon)